# Formulario con Login y Username base Spreadsheets que no envía a pagina

Tags: html, formularios, login, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un formulario escrito en Google Apps Script con Login que pide Username y Password, guarda los datos en una hoja de Sheets y posteriormente regresa los datos para dar acceso a otra página. Todo se desarrolla de manera correcta a exepción de que una vez hecho el login de manera afirmativa no me envía a la pagina solicitada. Me aparece un error al ejecutar la función checkLogin en el scipt de gs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined. anexo el codigo esperando su ayuda.

codigo.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var x = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  var y = x.evaluate();
  var z = y.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return z;}

 function checkLogin(username, password) {
 
var url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBWSJQNnml0Jf3z15GeqzaZTKwLst_tqcArDcAA5hwA/edit#gid=0';
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
var found_record = '';

for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++){

if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase() && 
 webAppSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue().toUpperCase() == password.toUpperCase()){
 found_record = 'TRUE';}}
 if(found_record == '') {
 
 found_record = 'FALSE';}

return found_record;}

function AddRecord(usernamee, passwordd, email, phone) {
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBWSJQNnml0Jf3z15GeqzaZTKwLst_tqcArDcAA5hwA/edit#gid=0';
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
webAppSheet.appendRow([usernamee,passwordd,email,phone]);}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script>
function AddRow()
{
  var usernamee = document.getElementById("usernamee").value;
  var passwordd = document.getElementById("passwordd").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  if (usernamee==""|| passwordd==""|| email==""|| phone=="") {
    return false;
  }
  else {
  google.script.run.AddRecord(usernamee,passwordd,email,phone);
  document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1-off";
  document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1";
 }
}

 function LoginUser()
{
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
{
  if(output == 'TRUE')
  {
     document.getElementById("displayusername").innerHTML = username;
     document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_class1-off";
     document.getElementById("page4_id1").className = "page4_id1";    
  }
  else if(output == 'FALSE')
  {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Invalid data";     
  }    
}).checkLogin(username, password);}

 function function1(){
document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_class1-off";
document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1";}

 function function3(){ 
document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1-off";
document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_id1"; }

</script>
<style>

/*page1*/
.page1_class1-off{
display: none;}


/*page2*/
.page2_class1{
display: none;}

.page2_id1-off{
display:none;}

/*page3*/
.page3_class1{
display:none;}
.page3_id1-off{
display:none;}

/*page4*/
.page4_class1{
display:none;}
.page4_id1-off{
display:none;}

input[type=text]:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;}
input[type=number]:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;}
input[type=password]:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;}

 .user{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 border: 8px solid black;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;}

 /*the head/*/
 .user::before{
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 left: calc(50% - 11px);
 top: 10px;}

 /*the body*/
.user::after{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width:50px;
height:40px;
background: black;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 24px);
top: 39px;}

</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<!--page1-->
<center>
<div class="page1_class1" id="page1_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;"> 
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
<br>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/>
<br><span id="errorMessage" style="color: red" ></span><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"  style="float: right;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 1px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight:bold;" /><br>
<br>
<b>If you don't have an account,</b><input type="button" onClick="function1()" value="Create New" style="margin-top: 5px;font-weight:bold;" />
</div>

<!--page2-->
<div class="page2_class1" id="page2_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;">
<h1>Create Account</h1>
<input type="text" id="usernamee" placeholder="Name" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
<br>
<input type="password" id="passwordd" placeholder="Create password" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size: 0.9;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;" /><br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Phone no." style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;" /><br><br>
<b style="color:red;">Password must contain letters and numbers. It will not work without letters and numbers.</b><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="AddRow()" style="float: right;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 1px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight:bold;" />
<br>
</div>

<!--page3-->
<div class="page3_class1" id="page3_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;"><center>
<h2> Your account has been successfully created. Login to your account</h2>
<input type="submit"  onClick="function3()" value="Login" style="font-weight:bold;"><br>
</div> 

<!--page4-->
<div class="page4_class1" id="page4_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;" ><center>
<br>
<h2>Hi <b id="displayusername" style="color:red;"></b>!</h2>
<div class="user"></div>
<h2> You are successfully logged in.</h2>
<h2>**************</h2>
<br>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la respuesta.

Solamente modifiqué el código en la parte de GS de la `function checkLogin` y borré `.toUpperCase()`.

Al borrar todos pudo correr de forma efectiva el formulario.